# Trying an inner_join within a dplyr do function

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using `dplyr::do` to calculate some values but I would like to join some data to it.

```
df2 <- data.frame(cat=c('a','a','b'),
                  cl=1,
                  id=c('A','B','C'))
df1 <- data.frame(cat=c('a','b'),
                 cl=1)
df1 %>%
  group_by(cat, cl) %>%
  do(ids=paste(. %>%
                 inner_join(df2) %>%
                 dplyr::select(id) %>%
                 unlist(), collapse=';'))
```

I get an error

> Error in as.vector(x, "character") : 
>     cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Has anyone an idea how to manage this or what exactly the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is using the dot as the left hand side of the piping operator, the documentation of `%>%` states :

> Using the dot-place holder as lhs
>   When the dot is used as lhs, the result will be a functional sequence, i.e. a function which applies the entire chain of right-hand sides in turn to its input. See the examples.

They even provide an example:

```
# Building unary functions with %>%
trig_fest <- . %>% tan %>% cos %>% sin
```

So basically you're providing a function as input to `paste`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, might have overlooked it! Also with the example @Rohit gave in his answer it works in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(cat, cl) %>%
  do(ids=paste(  inner_join(.,df2) %>%
                 dplyr::pull(id), collapse=';'))
```

Not sure exactly why it works, but it does.

Comment: or `(.) %>% inner_join(df2) ...`